# How do I set up Sencha Touch 2 locally to build for Phone Gap Cloud Service?

Tags: cordova, mobile, sencha-touch

I'd like to use the Phone Gap Cloud service to avoid having to manage native SDKs, creating seperate builds for Android, iOS etc. but I am confused as to how exactly to set it up for Sencha.

I understand how to say set up PhoneGap for Android in Eclipse, but how do I code the application if I plan on using the Cloud Build service? A few things are confusing me:

1. Do I download 'phonegap.js' from somewhere and include it in my index.html? Or is it just included automatically by the build service if I reference it?
2. If all the phonegap magic is happening through the cloud, how can I test locally?
3. The cloud build service offers a few plugins, e.g. ChildBrowser, Analytics, Barcode Scanner. Similarly do I have to download these plugins as well or just reference them?

Answer (score 0):

1. Just include `phonegap.js`. PhoneGap Build will add this file automatically to your build.
2. PhoneGap Build Service is for build automatisation process. If you need to test something locally then you have to install and configure local environment or just functional testing on the real device or emulator after application builds will be completed by the cloud service.
3. To use PhoneGap Build plugins you have to:

   - Include plugins JS file. Again, all files will be added automatically.
   - Include plugins native code adding something like `<gap:plugin name="Example" />` into `config.xml` file